# Error: INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to run different code based on the db instance using an if statement but I keep getting this error:

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 9, column 8: PLS-00428: an INTO clause
>   is expected in this SELECT statement
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

I'm trying to use a system variable to determine if i'm in prod, qa, dev, then run various statements based on where I am.

This is what I've tried:

```
DECLARE 
        ENV VARCHAR(256);
    BEGIN
        SELECT sys_context('USERENV','DB_NAME') AS Instance
        INTO ENV
        FROM dual;

        IF ENV = 'CSTMP' THEN
            CREATE MV_TEST_CSTMP ...;
        ELSIF ENV = 'PROD' THEN
            CREATE MV_TEST_PROD ...;
        ELSE
            CREATE MV_DEFAULT ...;
        END IF;
    END;
```

But I get: **PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement**

EDIT: I've also tried this

```
VAR ENV VARCHAR(255);

SELECT sys_context('USERENV','DB_NAME') AS Instance
INTO ENV
FROM DUAL;

IF ENV = 'CSTMP' THEN
    execute immediate 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST_CSTMP
    USING INDEX 
    REFRESH 
    NEXT trunc(SYSDATE, ''hh'') + 1/24       
    FORCE 
    USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT 
    ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS 
    SELECT count(m.work_ownerid)
            FROM MV_WWORK_SHRUNK m
            WHERE WORK_STATUS = 2';

ELSIF ENV = 'PROD' THEN
    execute immediate 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW PROD
    USING INDEX 
    REFRESH 
    NEXT trunc(SYSDATE, ''hh'') + 1/24       
    FORCE 
    USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT 
    ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS 
    SELECT count(m.work_ownerid)
            FROM MV_WWORK_SHRUNK m
            WHERE WORK_STATUS = 3';

ELSE
    execute immediate 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST_ELSE
    USING INDEX 
    REFRESH 
    NEXT trunc(SYSDATE, ''hh'') + 1/24       
    FORCE 
    USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT 
    ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS 
    SELECT count(m.work_ownerid)
            FROM MV_WWORK_SHRUNK m
            WHERE WORK_STATUS = 4';
END IF;
```

: **ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"**

Comment: What don't you understand?  A programming block needs for all queries to return values into variables.

Comment: What if I don't need that, is there a way to write an if/else where I'm not storing something in a variable?

Comment: I don't believe DDL is directly allowed in PL/SQL the way you wrote your CREATE statements.

Comment: So is there no way of creating tables, views, etc based on conditions?

Comment: You must use an `execute immediate` command to create your views. However, you should get a different error code for this mistake, not the one you reported. Is that the EXACT code you are running?

Comment: Yes there IS a way to create tables, views etc. based on conditions. You have syntax errors, not logical errors (perhaps), in your code.

Comment: This is not the exact code I'm running, the code between the if statement is simplified. I'll update OP with a closer representation of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You have to use execute immediate with your create view statement. You're getting a confusing parsing error because of the select clause in it.

Comment: Right right, just figured out how to use it, the rest needs to be in quotes. Okay trying that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working like this:

```
DECLARE 
 ENV VARCHAR(255);

BEGIN

    SELECT sys_context('USERENV','DB_NAME') AS Instance
    INTO ENV
    FROM DUAL;

    IF ENV = 'CSTMP' THEN
        execute immediate 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST_CSTMP
        USING INDEX 
        REFRESH 
        NEXT trunc(SYSDATE, ''hh'') + 1/24       
        FORCE 
        USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT 
        ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS 
        SELECT count(m.work_ownerid)
                FROM MV_WWORK_SHRUNK m
                WHERE WORK_STATUS = 2';

    ELSIF ENV = 'PROD' THEN
        execute immediate 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW PROD
        USING INDEX 
        REFRESH 
        NEXT trunc(SYSDATE, ''hh'') + 1/24       
        FORCE 
        USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT 
        ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS 
        SELECT count(m.work_ownerid)
                FROM MV_WWORK_SHRUNK m
                WHERE WORK_STATUS = 3';

    ELSE
        execute immediate 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST_ELSE
        USING INDEX 
        REFRESH 
        NEXT trunc(SYSDATE, ''hh'') + 1/24       
        FORCE 
        USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT 
        ENABLE QUERY REWRITE AS 
        SELECT count(m.work_ownerid)
                FROM MV_WWORK_SHRUNK m
                WHERE WORK_STATUS = 4';
    END IF;
END;
```